# How to get user's input and store it

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to develop a bot that accepts user input in this format month/day(example 2/20). After that, it will check for the database from which zodiac sign elements and from input that user-provided. Thank you

Comment: you need to format the string and extract the required data, for example, if the user input from discord was `4/8` then you can split the string at `/` character and store the outputs in the array, then you can process this data.

Comment: Welcome, SO is not a free code writing service. Show us what you have tried so far and we can help you with that. For more see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68790683/how-to-get-users-input-and-store-it#comment121572544_68790683), you can split the info at the `/`. This is how you can split it:

```js
const data = message.content.split("/"); //I don’t know the variable name for your message object
const [month, day] = data
//you can now check with month being the number string before the / and day being the number string after it
```

Here is a working example

```js
const str1 = "2/20";
const str2 = "5/12";
let data = str1.split("/");
let [month, day] = data;
console.log(`Month was ${month} and day was ${day}`);
data = str2.split("/");
[month, day] = data;
console.log(`Month was ${month} and day was ${day}`);
```